# Domain of $\arccos$

Tags: trigonometry, functions

I want to minimize a real valued function $$f(x) = \frac{2}{3} \cos(x)+1+ \frac{1}{9}\cos^2(x),$$ but it turns out that the minimum occurs at $x = \pi - \arccos 3$.

I am not sure what to conclude from this fact.
Does the minimum now occur at $x = \pi$, or how should I interpret the fact that $\arccos$ is only defined in the interval $[-1,1]$?

Comment: One would need to know the original problem to see what's going on. Perhaps it is an endpoint maximum. Perhaps it is a mistake.  Could you please edit your question to provide more information?

Comment: @André Nicolas I made the problem more concrete

Comment: Is your function $f(x) = \frac{2}{3}\cos(x)+1+ \frac{1}{9}\cos^2(x)$?

Comment: @Babak Sorouh yes

Comment: This is an increasing function of $\cos$ hence the minimum is at $x^*=\pi$, yielding $f(x^*)=\frac49$.

Comment: @did: You can answer a question by posting an answer.

Comment: @Gigili: What can we interpret about this problem when we see the graph of the function shows infinitely maximums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take
$$f'(x)=-\frac 2 3 \sin x - \frac 2 9 \cos x \sin x$$
and set it equal to zero, we find that all critical points occur when $\sin x =0$ or $\cos x = -3$. The latter is impossible (over the reals), so *all* critical points occur when $\sin x =0$. This implies that $x=n \pi$, where $n\in \mathbb Z$. Examining the original equation, it is clear that the minimums occur when $n$ is odd or, equivalently, for $x=2k\pi+\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the cosines are on the numerator:$$f'(x)=-\frac{\sin x+6\sin x\cos x}{27}=0\Longleftrightarrow x=k\pi\,,\,k\in\mathbb{Z}\,,\,\,or\,\,\cos x=-\frac{1}{6}$$I can't see how you got $\,\arccos 3\,$ there...

Comment: Actually $x$ need not be a multiple of $2\pi$, just of $\pi$ in order for $\sin x$ to be zero.

Comment: Indeed so. Thanks